# how to fix the SSL error in python when I try to install a library?

Tags: python, ssl, pip, package

I'm facing this error for a while! I'm using python 3.7.3 and pip version 19.0.3.

When I try to install any python library this error appears:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SS
LCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certif
icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/fpdf/
```

I already try add this command:

```
--trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org
```

but it isn't working! How can I solve this error?
Here is the error image [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU4EE.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+certificate+verify+failed%3A+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the pip and then it will install new certificate :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I already upgrade pip, but the error is still there

Comment: Last time that i got a similar issue i was facing a problem related to my openssl deprecated version

Comment: Is it possible to update my openssl? How?

Comment: pip install pyopenssl